Loop Calculations of A Spontaneous Broken gauge theory with fermions
Let me first rephrase the background. Consider adding a massless fermion to the spontaneously broken $U(1)$ gauge theory through a chiral interaction:
$$
\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}_{L}i \gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}\psi_{L}+ \bar{\psi}_{R}i \gamma_{\mu}{\partial}^{\mu}\psi_{R}-\lambda_f(\bar{\psi}\phi\psi_R+h.c.) \tag{1}
$$
Where $D_{\mu}\psi = {\partial }_{\mu} +ieA_{\mu}$ the scalar potential takes the form
$$
V(\phi )=-\mu \phi^{\star }\phi +\frac{\lambda }{4}(\phi^{\star}\phi)^2 \tag{2}
$$
Assume$\phi$ field acquires a non-zero vacuum-expectation-value,$<\phi >=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$ , and then expand $\phi$ around the vev,
$$
\phi =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(v+h+iG). \tag{3}
$$
Now here comes the key point, first draw all the one-loop Feynman diagrams for the 1PI two-point function for h field. Then We have to show that the  loops of unphysical states cancel against each other. My first question is then what are the unphysical states here. My assumption is that the Goldstone Bosons and ghosts fields from gauge-fixing procedure. However there are four Feynman diagrams that contain loops of this two kinds of particles:

It seems to me that they look quite unsymmetric, since after using the Feynman Rules to translate them, the integral does not seem to bear any resemblance in structure. Hence is it necessary to use brutal force to show them cancel each other?
If so, is there any easier methodology to deal with the integrals? If not, how can we explain they cancel from a physical point of view?
Thx a lot if you have the patience to answer this question 
